# What is the right situation to use HttpStatusCode.Ambiguous in Asp.net MVC controller action return type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What is the right place or use case to use return type as HttpStatusCode.Ambiguous in ASP.Net MVC controller action

Answer (score 0):

MSDN: Equivalent to HTTP status 300. Ambiguous indicates that the requested information has multiple representations. The default action is to treat this status as a redirect and follow the contents of the Location header associated with this response.

It is a 300 code which means that the server says the content is at another place.  In this case, it would likely be when the server can return multiple formats, but the client hasn't specified which format it wants.